# MySql like with %

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I am trying to execute a SQL query that will give me all usernames from my table which begin with 'Ana%'.

There are two rows like it:

1. Ana
2. Anastacia

My code is like:

```
$value="Ana"
$sql=mysql_query("Select username from users where username like {"."'".$value."%"."'}"); 

$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

print_r($row);
```

The problem is I get information only about user Ana, not Ana and Anastasia like it should be.

I tried without brackets `{}`, but it did not work.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using mysql_* functions and not PDO or mysqli?

Comment: @Mike Probably because he doesn't know that [they're deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Didn`t know that is deprecated. So It feels like I have to lear mysqli...

Comment: Anyone heard about quoting values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your LIKE clause should be

```
like '".$value."%'");
```

No `{` or `}`, and no need for all the extra concatenation. So the entire command would be

```
$sql=mysql_query("Select username from users where username like '".$value."%'");
```

That said, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and you are wide open to SQL injection, so you have bigger problems to worry about. You need to use PDO or MySQLi and prepared statements.

**Edit:** Also, you are not retrieving both rows of your data. [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) only fetches one row at a time, so you need to use a loop, like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: This also returns only Ana ..:( I will try with MySQLi

Comment: @user2854939 Make sure you are retrieving both rows. [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) only fetches one row at a time, so you need to use a loop. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$sql=mysql_query("Select username from users where username like '".$value."%'");
```